# How to evaluate these two integrals about hyperbolic functions?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, digamma-function

While I was calculating the two integrals below
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\cos x}{1+\cosh x-\sinh x}\mathrm{d}x\\
\mathcal{J}&=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{1+\cosh x-\sinh x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
I used series expansion,and the two integrals became the series below
$$\mathcal{I}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{n\cdot\left ( -1 \right )^{n}}{1+n^{2}}~,~\mathcal{J}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{ \left ( -1 \right )^{n}}{1+n^{2}}$$
but I don't know how to evaluate the two series,the WolframAlpha gave me the answer about digamma function:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}&=\frac{1}{4}\left [ \psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \right )+\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \right )-\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( 1-\frac{i}{2} \right )-\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( 1+\frac{i}{2} \right ) \right ]\\
\mathcal{J}&=\frac{i}{4}\left [ -\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \right )+\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \right )+\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( 1-\frac{i}{2} \right )-\psi ^{\left ( 0 \right )}\left ( 1+\frac{i}{2} \right ) \right ]
\end{align*}
I'd like to know is there a simple form for it or how to evaluate the two series.Without using series expansion,how to solve the two integrals.

**EDIT:**
I found a way to calculate the integral $\mathcal{J}$,I will post it later.

Comment: In what sense are the integrals being evaluated? In the classical sense they do not appear to converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But mathematica 9 shows $\displaystyle \mathcal{J}=\frac{1}{2} (1+\pi  \text{csch}(\pi ))$

Comment: @EvilNebula. It is funny in Mathematica. If we write $J$ as you did, then it gives the same [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0^\infty+%28sin%28x%29%29%2F%281%2Bcosh%28x%29-sinh%28x%29%29) as you. But I calculated by replacing the hyperbolics with exp and got a different [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0^\infty+%28sin%28x%29%29%2F%281%2Be^%28-x%29%29) which says it is not convergent. Then I started doubting basic math but it is [fine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28cosh%28x%29-sinh%28x%29%29+-+exp%28-x%29) .

Comment: @Arashium you can take a look at my latest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{J}=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{1+\cosh x-\sinh x}\mathrm{d} x&=\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin x}{1+e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-nx}\sin x\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}}{1+n^{2}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left ( 2n \right )^{2}+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left ( 2n +1\right )^{2}+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\coth \left ( \frac{\pi }{2} \right )-\frac{\pi }{4}\tanh\left ( \frac{\pi }{2} \right )\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi }{2}\mathrm{csch} \pi 
\end{align*}

Comment: Your first two integrals are divergent. When you turn that geometric series around, you have a problem when $n=0$ (giving $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin x\,dx$). The formula you used for integrating the product $e^{-nx}\sin x$ is _not_ valid for $n=0$.

Comment: @mickep but if you take a look at the interand image of the first integral,you will find it converges to the first curved line trangle's area.

Comment: The first what and where should I have a look?

Answer (score 1):

$$1+\cosh x +\sinh x=1+e^{-x}$$

$$I+i J=\int_0^{+\infty} {e^{ix} \over 1+e^{-x}} dx$$

**Update**

As mentioned by user mickep this integration does not converge. The denominator is converging to 1 and the numerator is fluctuating.

Comment: But now there was $1+\cosh x-\sinh x=1+e^{-x}$ in the denominator. This makes the integrand essentially look like $\cos x$ (and $\sin x$ respectively), and so the integrals are not convergent.

Comment: @mickep  I didnt get the point why it is not convergent.

Comment: Assume that $\int_0^{+\infty} \cos x/(1+e^{-x})\,dx$ is convergent. Then, adding the clearly convergent integral $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}/(1+e^{-x})\cos x\,dx$ we would find that the integral $\int_0^{+\infty}\cos x\,dx$ were convergent. But it is not.

Comment: why not introduce an exponential regulator?

Comment: @tired, If you have any idea about how to do that, please share it with us. I am not much happy of the answer I posted.

Comment: @Arashium Done!

Answer (score 0):

> *Wolfram Alpha gave me the answer about [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function): $$\begin{align*}
> \mathcal{I}&=\frac{1}{4}\left[+~\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right]\\
> \mathcal{J}&=\frac{i}{4}\left[-~\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right)-\psi^{\left(0\right)}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)\right]
> \end{align*}$$ But Mathematica $9$ shows* $\displaystyle\mathcal{J}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\pi\text{csch}(\pi)).$

**Hint:** Do you notice the recurrent expressions of the form $\psi_0(1\pm x)$ and $\psi_0\bigg(\dfrac12\pm x\bigg)$ ? 
 Now, are you aware of the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) and [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Reflection_relation), 
 which can be deduced by differentiating the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product 
 formula$($s$)$ for the $($co$)$sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) ?

Comment: Mathematica 10 correctly gives the answer that the integrals are divergent.

Comment: @mickep: I never said otherwise. All I did was showing **why** the two different expressions for $\mathcal J$ are equivalent.

Comment: And I just said that Mathematica 10 correctly was claiming the integrals to be divergent... Calm down :)

Comment: @Lucian Out of curiosity, why are both [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqmsyuag5q) and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+re%28sin%28x%29%2F%281%2Bcosh%28x%29-sinh%28x%29%29%29+from+0+to+50) both unable to plot past $x\approx 39.3$? However, inputting, $\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{-x}+1}$ does not have this error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: interand image]

The picture shows that the integral isn't divergent.